# Checkout a file from a remote branch and rename it

Tags: git, shell

I would like to know if it's possible to checkout a file from a remote branch to my local branch and also rename it.

For instance:

(master) /my-project/my-awesome-file.txt

I would like to get the file by executing
`git checkout master my-awesome-file.txt ---> my-file.txt`

So, instead of replacing my-awesome-file.txt it would create a copy of it (from master) and name it my-file.txt

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+checkout+file+different+name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could retrieve the file content via `git show <revision>:<path>` and just write it in the file to create.

```
git show master:my-awesome-file.txt > myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you normally *check out* (or switch to) an entire *commit*.  This extracts all the files from that commit.  To extract a single file from a particular commit, you can limit `git checkout`, or use `git restore`, but these two do not allow you to rename the file.

What you *can* do quite easily is *display* a file from a particular commit.  Simply write down the commit's name—its hash ID, or some proxy for its hash ID—followed by a colon `:` and the path-name of that file within that commit.  Give this as an argument to `git show` or `git cat-file -p`.  For instance:

```
git show master:my-awesome-file.txt
```

or:

```
git show a123456:path/to/file.txt
```

The output goes to the *standard output*, which you can *redirect* anywhere you like:

```
git show ${hash}:${path} > $out
```

where `hash`, `path`, and `out` are shell variables (or expand them in place with whatever you like), so:

```
git show master:my-awesome-file.txt > /tmp/foo.txt
```

If you redirect the output to a file in your current working directory, which is part of your work-tree, that file is now in your work-tree:

```
git show master:my-awesome-file.txt > my-file.txt
```

#### Notes about untracked files

If this file is not in Git's *index* (aka *staging area*), it is now an *untracked file* and will show up as such in `git status` unless the name of the file matches a directive in a `.gitignore` or similar file.

Note that the `.gitignore` file doesn't list files to be *ignored*, really.  Instead, it lists files that, *if untracked*, Git should *not complain about*.  If the file *is* tracked—that is, if its name appears in Git's index *right now*—the file is not ignored, even if its name is listed in `.gitignore`.  This means that the name `.gitignore` is a misnomer: it should be instead `.git-do-not-complain-about-these-files-if-they-are-untracked`.  But that doesn't cover everything `.gitignore` does either, so it should maybe be something even longer and less usable.  But the longer and less usable this file's name gets, the more ridiculous it is, so Git just calls it `.gitignore` even though that's the wrong name.

Normally, `git status` *complains about* untracked files, as a reminder to you that you should use `git add` to make them tracked.  But if the file should never be `git add`-ed, this complaint is worse than useless.  So `.gitignore` lets you list files that (a) Git should not complain about, and (b) Git should *skip over* if you use an en-masse "add everything" operation like `git add .`.  The skipping-over part is the main sense in which these files are really "ignored".  The not-complaining is also a *kind* of ignoring, perhaps.  But if the file is *tracked*—if it's gotten into Git's index somehow, perhaps by you running `git add --force` for instance—then it's not ignored at all.

How do you know if a file is tracked?  The answer is usually "you don't".  If `git status` doesn't *complain* about it, it could be because it's untracked, but it could be because you didn't *change* it.  But in most cases, if you didn't change it, you don't care anyway, so you don't even have to ask "is this file tracked" in the first place.  If `git status` *does* complain about it, saying that it is untracked, then it must be untracked, and if `git status` says that it's *changed*—and either to be committed, or not yet to be committed—then it's tracked.  (Or, you can use `git ls-files --staged` to see *everything* in Git's index, but this is usually way too much information, like one of my answers here. )